Why isn't the "Anchored" keyword working on grouped parts?
I made a building out of parts, and grouped them together in order to move it easier. However, when I tried attaching a script to it that used the Anchored keyword, it did not work. Here is the code:
task.wait(5)

script.Parent.Anchored = false

I expected the building to fall apart after 5 seconds, but it did not. I did some experimentation and the same problem applied to other grouped parts. Could someone please tell me a simple way to apply a script to a large amount of parts, with the "Anchored" keyword allowed?

When you group parts, it creates a Model, which is its own separate object. Applying changes to the Model does not necessarily impact its children. So a simple way to make changes is to use the Model:GetDescendants() function, which will give you a list of all of the objects in the hierarchy, and you can unanchor them manually.
Also, if you have assembled the model yourself, there is a good chance that there are Welds holding the model together, so if you want it to fall apart, be sure to destroy these as well.
So you can do something like this.
local model : Model = script.Parent

wait(5.0)

-- remove the anchors and welds holding the thing together
local children = model:GetDescendants()
for i, child in ipairs(children) do
    if child:IsA("Weld") then
        child:Destroy()
    elseif child:IsA("BasePart") then
        child.Anchored = false
    end
end

-- if your building needs a little... convincing to fall apart...
local force = Instance.new("Explosion")
force.BlastRadius = model:GetExtentsSize().Magnitude
force.Position = model:GetPivot().Position
force.TimeScale = 1
force.Visible = false
force.ExplosionType = Enum.ExplosionType.NoCraters
force.Parent = model


Instead of calling the Model.Anchored property, make a part of your model the PrimaryPart. Then use the code like this Model.PrimaryPart.Anchored=false. This means all of the parts of the model revolve around the PrimaryPart, including the descendants, and they all follow the part's copyable properties.
This means I don't have to manually set each part to anchored if I have two parts in a model.
Here's a quick example: (This code makes use of a model with multiple parts)
local model=script.Parent
model.PrimaryPart.Anchored=false

Hope this helped!
